# Ubuntu 12.04 cloud-init doesn't support "write_files", what to do?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, cloud-init

I'm using cloud-init to setup Ubuntu VMs on EC2. I've recently had need to support deployment using Ubuntu 12.04 (old LTS) images, but the old cloud-init 0.6.3 that is in Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't support the `write_files` module that I need.

I'm currently hacking it using `runcmd` and bash, but this is hardly the correct way to handle adding files to a system.

Any ideas for a better workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't have an elegant solution, but my hack using `runcmd` and Ruby (which may or may not be installed on your base image, so you may need to list it in `packages`) looks like this:

```
runcmd:
  - - ruby
    - -ryaml
    - -rfileutils
    - -rzlib
    - -rstringio
    - -e
    - |
        ud=%x{curl -s http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/user-data}
        ud = Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(ud)).read unless ud[0] = "#"
        YAML.load(ud)["write_files"].each { |f|
          FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f["path"]))
          File.open(f["path"], "w") { |io| io.write(f["content"]) }
          File.chmod(f["permissions"].to_i(8), f["path"]) 
        }
```

This hack also works from relatively recent Amazon Linux instances which have a recent cloud-init, but for some reason have the `write_files` module disabled.

The code assumes user-data is either the plain text `#cloud-config` or a gzip compression of that. If using something more complicated, such as multi-part or includes, then you may want to read the parsed data from `/var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt.i`, but that requires MIME parsing - which I'll leave as an exercise to the reader :-).