# cloud-init module order is wrong, how to fix?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, cloud-init

I'm using cloud-init to setup AWS EC2 machines running Ubuntu 14.04. One of the more useful features of cloud-init is the `write_files` module that allows me to install additional files during the initialization of the virtual machine.

`write_files` has several useful functions, among them is setting the owner of the file, as [documented here](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/examples.html#writing-out-arbitrary-files). Unfortunately, it appears that I can't use this feature of `write_files` in Ubuntu 14.04 to set the file owner to any non-system account, because the cloud-init module that adds users - ["users groups"](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/examples.html#including-users-and-groups) is being run after the `write_files` section. If I set file owner to a user that is added in the `users` section (or in my case the default `users`), even if I do this by uid, I get errors such as this:

```
StandardError:('write-files', OSError("Unknown user or group: 'getpwnam(): name not found: ubuntu'",))
```

This seems coded into /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg, which has this section:

```
cloud_init_modules:
 - migrator
 - seed_random
 - bootcmd
 - write-files
 - growpart
 - resizefs
 - set_hostname
 - update_hostname
 - update_etc_hosts
 - ca-certs
 - rsyslog
 - users-groups
 - ssh
```

I've seen a few examples on the internet that set `cloud_init_modules` in the cloud-init user data, but if I add such a section and order it so `write-files` is under `users-groups`, it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Aside from giving up on `write_files` and implementing a `runcmd` based workaround as documented in [question #605670](https://serverfault.com/questions/605670/ubuntu-12-04-cloud-init-doesnt-support-write-files-what-to-do) is there anything else that can be done?

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same [bug #1231541](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1231541).
As I had the problem in OpenStack, I used packer to rebuild the image and change the order of the cloud-init modules. Afterwards everything worked as expected.

Comment: Updating images by hand is always an option, and always a bad option :-) I prefer to work directly with upstream whenever possible